# Authenticated REST API call to Azure Service Bus using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

Azure Service Bus supports managed identity access, however the only method I've found to for example send a message to a queue is using this approach that requires code and the Service Bus SDK:

```
var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedServiceIdentityTokenProvider();
QueueClient sendClient = new QueueClient($"sb://{Config.Namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/", Config.Queue, tokenProvider);
await sendClient.SendAsync(new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageInfo.MessageToSend)));
await sendClient.CloseAsync();
```

Sources:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-servicebus-dotnet
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity

I'm looking for a way to do the same thing with a REST API call from within an Azure API Management policy. I've granted APIM, role based access to Service Bus and I'm able to get a token back, but I get this error back from Service Bus when attempting the REST API call with the managed identity token passed in the Authorization header:

```
MalformedToken: The credentials contained in the WRAP header are not well-formed.
```

It looks like Service Bus might only support WRAP or SAS tokens at this point with their REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-batch

But then again how is this working behind the scenes?

```
TokenProvider.CreateManagedServiceIdentityTokenProvider()
```

Seems like it should be possible with the REST API.

Comment: Seems like it assigns the token to the Authorization header, seems pretty standard :\

Comment: Hmm, but it could be that they don't specify it as `Authorization: Bearer tokenabcdef.....` but as `Authorization: tokenabcdef`.

Comment: @juunas I couldn't find any documentation on this unfortunately. I tried using the <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://servicebus.azure.net" /> APIM policy. It uses the "Bearer {token}" format, but SB doesn't like it.

Comment: @juunas You were right! It works with just the token value. No prefix. I wonder why this isn't documented. If you add that as an answer I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in the SDK they don't specify it as `Authorization: Bearer tokenabcdef.....` but as `Authorization: tokenabcdef`. Which is a bit unusual.